# Oracle regexp_replace numbers for letters

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I think this should be simple but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it other than nesting `regexp_replace`. I want to replace each number with a corresponding letter something like:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('147','1','A'),'4','D'),'7','G')
```

result:

> ADG

but with a list operator like this

```
regexp_replace('12345','[1234567890]','[ABCDEFGHIJ]')
```

but of course instead of ADG I get

> [ABCDEFGHIJ][ABCDEFGHIJ][ABCDEFGHIJ][ABCDEFGHIJ][ABCDEFGHIJ]

Comment: How do we know that 147 represents the first, fourth and seventh letter and not - for example - fourteenth and seventh?

Comment: You're going to need the nested regexp_replace() calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for this; you need the TRANSLATE function:

```
select translate('147', '1234567890', 'ABCDEFGHIJ') as translated from dual;

TRANSLATED
-------------
ADG
```

Answer (score 1):

**This can't be easily done with `REGEXP_REPLACE`.**

Regex doesn't really have the power to decide what to replace based on what it matches; it's usually only meant to make *a* match and leave the rest up to whatever programming language you're using. You might be able to swing this in something like Python, but as has been pointed out in another answer, for Oracle, `REGEXP_REPLACE` is the wrong tool for the job.